# Third party libraries on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, vendor

I have added the GNU library 'wdiff' to my Ruby on Rails application via https://github.com/echan00/wdiff and added the executable to my `/vendor/usr/bin` directory.

Via `heroku run bash` I am able to execute the `wdiff` library at `~/vendor/usr/bin`.

I have added `/app/vendor/usr/bin` as a `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable but my Ruby on Rails application cannot find `wdiff`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the code your app uses and what do you type in the heroku console?

Comment: "./wdiff a.txt b.txt" to test run the executable in bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have added `/app/vendor/usr/bin` as a `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable but my Ruby on Rails application cannot find `wdiff`

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` [tells the OS where to find libraries to be dynamically linked at runtime](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/45106/12606). For example, if you're running an application that requires OpenSSL but doesn't include OpenSSL itself the operating system can find it via `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Directories the OS should search for *binaries* are listed in the `PATH` variable. Try using that instead.

Note that it would be very unusual to just set this to a single value. A more common approach would be to prepend or append your custom location to whatever value `PATH` already has, e.g. via something like

```
export PATH="$PATH:/app/vendor/usr/bin"
```

In case multiple binaries with the same name exist, ones found earlier in the path take precedence over ones found later.

Finally, something Heroku-specific:

> and added the executable to my `/vendor/usr/bin` directory

How did you do this? If the binary is part of your repository you should be okay, but if you've added it manually (e.g. via `heroku run bash`) you'll find that it disappears after a certain amount of time. This is due to Heroku's [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem).

You'll need to include `wdiff` at build time. One good way of doing that would be by [adding a second buildpack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app) like [`heroku-buildpack-apt`](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt) and then installing the regular `wdiff` package via your `Aptfile`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up hard-coding my rails gem to find the executable in the directory instead of going through the LIBRARY PATH